# How to parse a JSON array containing a single item nested in another object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am calling the CodeCollaborator API using Json.Net from a C# program.

I am receiving the following JSON in an HttpResponse from the API.

```
[{"result":{"loginTicket":"c9c6793926517db05bde47d3dd50026e"}}]
```

How can I parse it to create the LoginTicketResponse object mentioned below?

```
public class LoginTicketResponse
{
    public string loginTicket { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following code but no luck.

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(result);
foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {                        
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(p.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/1870760

Comment: Simple search on google will give you too many useful links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can do this with `DeserializeObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off.  In your inner loop change this line:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(p.ToString());
```

to this:

```
LoginTicketResponse stuff = p.Value.ToObject<LoginTicketResponse>();
```

Or if you know that there will only be one item in the response, you can simplify the whole thing to this:

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(result);
LoginTicketResponse stuff = a[0]["result"].ToObject<LoginTicketResponse>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You might benefit much from JSON.NET it's a NuGet package which is easy to install. With that package you can easily write:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginTicketResponse>(jsonString);
```

Comment: OP is already using Json.Net; it says so in the question.  Also, the line of code you wrote will not correctly parse the JSON given in the question, as the `LoginTicketResponse` is inside an object which is inside an array.